# Javascript: Linkedin Access TOken

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I would like to integrate my application with linkedin. User would be able to connect(Login) with Linkedin and post to user's wall.

In order to post to user's wall, I need access token.
If I use access token that I got from IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token, I got Invalid acces token error.

I tried to follow instructions here, https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2. I got valid access token and I was successful to post to user’s wall.

Is there any way to exchange access token in Javascript or I need to follow that instructions to get valid access token?
Is there any documentation since this tutorial is broken
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api?

Comment: I put the codes to capture access token here http://jsfiddle.net/rsakura/osar4po0/ .